# I want to select date only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, date

This is my query:

```
select c.InFavourOf as name,
       c.ChequeDate,
       p.Amount as amount,
       m.No as CNo
from Cheque c
  inner join PaymentDetail p 
    on c.MasterID= p.PaymentMasterID
  inner join PaymentMaster m 
    on p.ID=m.ID
```

Result:

[image: at the time of execute this code this result is showing . i want to select date only in the order of dd mm yyyy]

I want the date values in column `ChequeDate` formatted as `dd mm yyyy` without the time part.

How can I do that?

Comment: I have modified your question to what I believe you are asking. If I have misunderstood you please edit your question to what you want it to be.

Comment: @Arun Vadakkedath, SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()); only returns the date part in SQL server 2008 and higher version..

Comment: Why don't you provide the formatting in your presentation layer (your application, probably)?

Answer (score 1):

The [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function can do that. And if you want `dd mm yyyy` format 103 (with `/` separator) or 104 (with `.` separator) would be fine.

```
select c.InFavourOf as name,
       convert(varchar(10), c.ChequeDate, 103),
       p.Amount as amount,
       m.No as CNo
from Cheque c
  inner join PaymentDetail p 
    on c.MasterID= p.PaymentMasterID
  inner join PaymentMaster m 
    on p.ID=m.ID
```

If you want `space` separator, use [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en_us/library/ms186862.aspx) function.

```
replace(convert(varchar(10), c.ChequeDate, 103), '/', ' ')
```

Comment: It will give "convert(varchar(10), c.ChequeDate, 103)" ,  Result with (No Column Name). Untill unless when you shall not use as alias like that convert(varchar(10), c.ChequeDate, 103) as ChequeDate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.InFavourOf as name,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.ChequeDate, 103) as ChequeDate  ,
       p.Amount as amount,
       m.No as CNo
from Cheque c
  inner join PaymentDetail p 
    on c.MasterID= p.PaymentMasterID
  inner join PaymentMaster m 
    on p.ID=m.ID
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the CONVERT parameters you've used.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable you want to display as date and not the time you can use the convert function that others have shown or you can format your own string with other SQL-SERVER functions

```
select c.InFavourOf as name,
   DATEPART(DAY, c.ChecqueDate) AS day, DATEPART(MONTH,c.ChecqueDate) AS MONTHH, DATEPART(YEAR, c.ChecqueDate) AS YEAR as ChequeDate  ,
   p.Amount as amount,
   m.No as CNo
from Cheque c
inner join PaymentDetail p 
on c.MasterID= p.PaymentMasterID
inner join PaymentMaster m 
on p.ID=m.ID
```

Hopefully at least one of the answers here will put you in the right track :)